# caffe: 5D blobs pooling?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I have a 5D blob like `1x8x128x128` and I have a Convolution layer which is able to process my 5D blob. When I want to use a pool layer though it does not work. How do you use a `pool-layer` with a 5D blob?

> Check failed: 4 == bottom[0]->num_axes() (4 vs. 5) Input must have 4
>   axes, corresponding to (num, channels, height, width)

I think it is just not supported yet by caffe. Could I just use a convolution layer and do the `pooling`?

Comment: you can (1) implement ND pooling layer for caffe. or (2) if you only pool the first 2 spatial dimensions, you can reshape to 4D, pool, and reshape back to 5D

Comment: Ok and how do you omit a dimension and then reshape again and add one dimension again? I know how to add a dimension but I do not know how to omit a dimension. @Shai

Comment: Another choice is setting `stride = 2` in the convolution layer instead of being followed by a pooling layer, to realize the subsampling.

Comment: @Dale striding is **not** pooling: stride will skip/sample every X pixels, while pooling will take the max/avg of the pixels in its kernel. striding without proper filtering might lead to aliasing.

Comment: @thigi BTW, have you considered opening a request at BVLC\caffe github?

Comment: Have you seen this link: [pull request](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/3515)? I think this should be enough, or do you think I should open a request?  @Shai

Comment: @Shai agree to your point.

Comment: @thigi I'm not sure this pull request deals with ND pooling, it only changes the cuDNN support. You'll have to give it a closer look.

Comment: Yeah I know, but cuDNN support is fine isnt it? But I might open a request. @Shai

Comment: Here I have created it. But I am not very good at formulating. [issue](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/5048) @Shai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pool only the first two spatial dimensions, you can `"Reshape"` to 4D ("squashing" the channel and temporal dimensions), pool and then `"Reshape"` back to 5D:

```
layer {
  name: "pool/reshape4D"
  type: "Reshape"
  bottom: "in"
  top: "pool/reshape4D"
  reshape_param { axis: 1 num_axes: 1 shape { dim: -1 } }
}
layer {
  name: "pool"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "pool/reshape4D"
  top: "pool"
  # pooling params here...
}
layer {
  name: "pool/reshape5D"
  type: "Reshape"
  bottom: "pool"
  top: "pool/reshape5D"
  reshape_param { axis: 1 num_axes: 1 shape { dim: -1 dim: <temporal_dim> } } # replace <.> with the actual temporal dimension size.
}
```

See the definition of `ReshapeParameter` in [`caffe.proto`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L998-L1060) for more details.

Comment: My dimensions are not temporal but proper 3D slices but should not make a difference. I was thinking of giving the net my 2D image in form of a 4D blob and at the end when it comes to the loss I will reshape my 4D blob to a 5D blob and use a `Softmax` for a 5D blob if that is even possible. But I will try this answer here as well! Thanks! @Shai